# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException? any clue?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

here's my code that I am using now but still getting all kinds of errors:

```
No visible @interface for 'HomeViewController' declares the selector 'getCount'
```

And

```
/Volumes/Lex/HomeViewController.h:12:12: Required for direct or indirect protocol 'UIPickerViewDataSource'
/Volumes/Lexar/HomeViewController.m:15:17: Incomplete implementation
```

My code (.m file)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if (currentUser) {
        NSLog(@"Current user: %@" , currentUser.username);
    }
    else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];

        self.pickerView.dataSource = self;
        self.pickerView.delegate = self;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:  (NSInteger)component
{
    if ([self getCount] == 0)
        return 1;
    return [self getCount];
}

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:     (NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    if ([self getCount] == 0)
        return nil;
}

- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender {
    [PFUser logOut];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
}
@end
```

And the header

```
/// .h controller

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource,    UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;

- (IBAction)logout:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: Please share related code.

Comment: I dont have any code, that's the thing. I just placed the picker in the controller via storyboard and then when I test run the app it throws that error when I tap the unpopulated picker

Comment: I just tried recreating and reassign the .h and .m classes, but that didn't work. then I tried rebuilding the storyboard interface from scratch and that didn't work. I'm not really sure what else to do :/

Comment: Than I think you haven't implemented data source methods for UIPickerView. implement those to get it worked.

Comment: please explain. I'm a rook.

Comment: @Hirengardhariya- How are you bro BTW?

Comment: @JaredGross-Check the answer

Comment: Look at the first error message - no interface visible for `getCount`. Also an incomplete implementation. That's the class that we need to see the code for.

Comment: get count is the method to return no of count of rows to display

Comment: i got the errors to disappear for the most part. Now all I am getting is a warning stating 'control may reach end of non-void function'. But I am still having the same problem with the simulator.

Comment: control may reach end of non-void function indicates that you are returning nothing but the declaration of function expect somthing to return

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your comment, you are just placing `UIPickerView`...but for using picker view you need to set Datasource like `UITableView` and have to implement all `@required` methods.

In picker view's data source protocol, there are 2 @required methods

```
// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;

// returns the # of rows in each component..
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

So you need to implement above two method in your controller (say `MainViewController`). and don't forget to set this class as delegate and datasource to UIPicker view as below

in `ViewDidLoad` of `MainViewController`

```
self.yourPickerView.datasource = self;
self.yourPickerView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: okay, I was unaware I had to do that. Cause when I first put the picker in it was working fine. Then I deleted it and changed some things around in my code and when I put it back in I kept getting this error. I'll try that and let ya know how it goes, thanks!